# Magento 2 Product collection AddAttributeToFilter with AND/OR and !findinset and is null

Tags: magento2, database, collection, product-collection

How can i add " `AND (at_product_userclass.value IS NULL) OR !FIND_IN_SET('1', at_product_userclass.value)`" filter condition using addAttributeToFilter in product collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To filter by null values, you can use this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    'name_of_field',
    ['null' => true]
);
```

To use mysql query in collection, use this:

```
$collection->where(new \Zend_Db_Expr('[your_sql_expression]'));
```